# How do I conditionally format if value extracted is > number value?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a use case where I need to conditionally format a cell if the extracted value from this formula is greater than 5.

```
=trim(MID(C3:AZ,FIND("-",C3:AZ)+1,FIND("pts",C3:AZ)-FIND("-",C3:AZ)-1))>5
```

When I lock the cell references, I still don't get any conditional formatting, even though it accepts the formula:

```
=trim(MID($C$3:$AZ,FIND("-",$C$3:$AZ)+1,FIND("pts",$C$3:$AZ)-FIND("-",$C$3:$AZ)-1))>5
```

When I do the formula referencing a single cell, I get the expected output:
[image: Expected Output]

I've made an [example Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WocmEnuzF_T3lXrov4SmZFtotQVyo9IC_N5LWhmNok4/edit?usp=sharing) for reference, if you'd like to take a look at the sample dataset.

Any help/advice you all could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula. The way conditional formatting works is if the range for conditional formatting starts on A3, then you can put that one cell as the checking value, and the spreadsheet is smart enough to then check each cell in the range separately. I put a value around it as well since "trim" makes it a text instead of a number.

=value(trim(MID(A3,FIND("-",A3)+1,FIND("pts",A3)-FIND("-",A3)-1)))>5

Comment: Thanks, @Eliana! That worked perfectly. Also, thanks for explaining how the formula works with Conditional Formatting. It definitely makes sense.